# How to set MPMoviePlayerController playing remote videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

There's a MPMoviePlayerController * movieplayer, and it will play remote mp4 files on server, code likes this:

```
movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
movieplayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
movieplayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
[self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];
```

There are two buttons, abutton, bbutton, abutton calls playing a.mp4

```
NSString *VideoUrl = @"http://domain.com/a.mp4";
movieplayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VideoUrl];
[movieplayer play];
```

bbutton calls playing b.mp4

```
NSString *VideoUrl = @"http://domain.com/b.mp4";
movieplayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VideoUrl];
[movieplayer play];
```

I have some questions:

1. how to determine the movieplay is playing and finish playing? use stop?
2. if a.mp4 is playing, and I click bbutton, it will call playing b.mp4, but there still plays a.mp4 a second, and jump to b.mp4 and plays it.
3. how to preload the videos? I think preplay doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1)** To check if your MPMoviePlayerController is playing you can check the `playbackState`, defined as it:

```
enum {
   MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward
};
typedef NSInteger MPMoviePlaybackState;
```

If its value is `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying`, your player is currently playing a content.

**2)** Correct, but before playing a new content I suggest you to stop previous one, waiting for player notification (player notifies you its state changes) and then play the new one.

**3)** It is already done by the player: when you play a content, the player starts to load the content: the playback starts only when the buffer has enough data (so the preload is already done by the player).
You can check the `loadState` var that can have one of this value:

```
enum {
   MPMovieLoadStateUnknown        = 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlayable       = 1 << 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK  = 1 << 1,
   MPMovieLoadStateStalled        = 1 << 2,
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieLoadState;
```

If the player loadStateis MPMovieLoadStatePlayable, then the playback can start.

For more information please refers to the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the MoviePlayer playing status add a notification :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

You can add a notification to know when your player successfully load a video as well.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

About simply knowing if a player is currently playing or not you can just use

```
MoviePlayer.isPlaying
```

Have you considered initiating two different movie players for each movie and simply switching them? It will make the transition smoother i believe.